# PHP/MYSQL counting orders

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Orders table:

[image]

Order_items table:

[image]

Users table:

[image: Users]

```
$sql[2] = "SELECT u.name, COUNT(o.user_id) AS order_count, (oi.quantity * p.price) AS total_price FROM users AS u
        INNER JOIN orders AS o ON u.id = o.user_id
        INNER JOIN order_items AS oi ON oi.order_id = o.id
        INNER JOIN products AS p ON p.id = oi.product_id
        GROUP BY u.name
        ORDER BY ertek DESC";
```

I want to count how much order have every user. Example: Like Thomas have 3 order, but my code is writing 1, i want to write Thomas (3). And how much money spent, but this one is working fine. Any idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below query.

```
select u.name, (select count(*) from orders o where o.user_id=u.id) as 
order_count, (select sum(oi.quantity * p.price) from orders AS o INNER 
JOIN order_items AS oi ON oi.order_id = o.id INNER JOIN products AS p ON
p.id = oi.product_id where o.user_id=u.id) as total_price from users u
```

May be this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are asking for, the query should look like:

```
SELECT u.name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT o.id) as order_count,
-------------^
       SUM(oi.quantity * p.price) as total_price
-------^
FROM users u INNER JOIN
     orders o
     ON u.id = o.user_id INNER JOIN
     order_items oi
     ON oi.order_id = o.id INNER JOIN
     products p
     ON p.id = oi.product_id
GROUP BY u.name
ORDER BY order_count DESC;  -- I assume `ertek` is just a translation issue
```

I've highlighted the important changes.

Comment: dosnt work. its only counting 7 (Erik 3 - Gracian 2 - Alex 1 - Thomas 1), but i have more orders than 7, any another idea how to fix it ?